# Unable to use Converter with Avalonia

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, avalonia

I am unable to use a converter in XAML. I followed [the documentation](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/guides/data-binding/how-to-create-a-custom-data-binding-converter) however it seems incorrect or outdated.

```cs
namespace Mazes.Ui.Temporary.Converters
{
    public class TimeSpanConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object? Convert(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
           // ...
        }
    }
}
```

I register the converter in `MainWindow` where the window is declared.

```xml
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="using:Mazes.Ui.Temporary.ViewModels"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Mazes.Ui.Temporary.Views"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Mazes.Ui.Temporary.Converters;assembly=Mazes.Ui.Temporary"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
        x:Class="Mazes.Ui.Temporary.Views.MainWindow"
        Icon="/Assets/avalonia-logo.ico"
        Title="Mazes.Ui.Temporary">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:TimeSpanConverter x:Key="timeSpanConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <views:MainView />
</Window>
```

I then try to use it in `MainView` where it is bound to a property in the view model.

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{CompiledBinding ComputeTime, Converter={StaticResource timeSpanConverter}}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

However I get the following error in both `MainView` and `MainWindow`: `Static resource 'timespanConverter' not found.`

Comment: Tried right now with version 11.0.10 and it works as the documentation says. Is the 's' in 'timespanConverter' a typo? If you comment the TextBlock with the converter, does everything compiles ok?

Comment: This is very strange. I don't have any typos I can see: `timeSpanConverter`

Comment: Just in case: your TimeSpanConverter implements ConvertBack too, doesn't it? If your TimeSpanConverter class compiles ok, and there are not any other errors I don't know what's happening there. I created a new converter which always returns a string and used in a view this way. The only difference is I used a binding to a VM variable:
`code`<TextBlock Text="{Binding User.Name, Converter={StaticResource sConverter}}" />`/code`
. Try commenting the TextBlock line to discard any other errors.

Comment: It implements it yeah. Commenting the line out shows there's no other errors too. Do you also have the converter registered in MainWindow, and then used in MainView?

Comment: No, only in the view. The view has the xmlns:converters="clr- ..." and the resources line like yours... Perhaps this is the problem. Define and use it only in the view that uses it, MainView in your case.